# Sync Object3d rotation (tab level)

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

Need help,

I'm trying to sync the rotation of one object loaded in the active browser tab with another object loaded in the second tab. While rotating Object loaded in the active browser tab will send a message to another. In the second tab will listen to the message sent from the first tab and rotate the Object accordingly using rotation values. my code looks like below, (I  referred [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/n6u6asza/) example)

```
 let objectLoaded;
 let previousMousePosition = {x : 0,  y : 0 };
    function mouseDown(e) {
        isDragging = true;
    }

    function mouseUp() {
        isDragging = false;
        if (objectLoaded) {
            // publishing the rotation value to another tab using 'hermes' package.
            hermes.send('rotation', JSON.stringify({
                rotation: objectLoaded.rotation,
                quaternion: objectLoaded.getWorldQuaternion(),
                matrix: objectLoaded.matrixWorld
            })); 
        }
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        const deltaMove = { x : e.offsetX - previousMousePosition.x,y : e.offsetY - previousMousePosition.y };         
        if (isDragging && objectLoaded) {
            const deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1), toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1), 0, 'XYZ'));
            objectLoaded.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, objectLoaded.quaternion);
        }
        previousMousePosition = {x : e.offsetX,  y : e.offsetY };
    }

    function toRadians(angle) {
         return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    }
```

Listener code,

```
  hermes.on('rotation', (rotationObj) => {
  // rotationObj structure: {rotation: { _x: 0, _y: 0: _z: 0}, quaternion: { _x: 0, _y: 0: _z: 0, _w: 0}}
      const target = JSON.parse(rotationObj);
      SecondObject.rotateX(target.rotation._x);
      SecondObject.rotateY(target.rotation._y);
      SecondObject.rotateZ(target.rotation._z);
 })
```

The issue here is the second object not properly syncing with the first one. Do any one know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one tab, you request the current (absolute) rotation. In the other the, you rotate by those values in *addition* to the current rotation. That will break right after the first time you set a non-zero rotation.

What you want is to *assign* the rotation, by doing

```
SecondObject.rotation.copy(target.rotation);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day.

Comment: the syncing issue still exists. If I rotate more than twice in different angles the second object going out of sync.

Comment: Here is the gif demo - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uKzB_LIkl-Elw9Z_0o6gVo60ytYFzqRi/view

Comment: Actually, I was doing wrong. I was using orbit control with controls.enableRotate = true; It should be false.